# Unable to call functions (stored in bulk collect) in execute immediate

Tags: oracle, plsql, toad

I have a column(USING_FUNCTION) of function names E.g GET_FUNCTION(#value#) and another column (VALUE) which contains the vaule to be used

I'm trying to concentrate the function name and value into a bulk operator using:

```
Select (substr(using_function, 1, instr(using_function, '(', -1) -1)) 
        || '(' || value || ')' 
bulk collect into V_value 
from table1 
where using_function != 'N';
```

Then use execute immediate to call the function ( E.g Executing GET_WEEK_DATE(-2) will give me 16-SEP-2015 )before inserting it into another table (table2):

```
Execute immediate ' insert into table2 (name,value) select name, '
      || V_value ||' from table1 where using_function != ''N''';
```

I'm getting an error: Wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'.

*ps I'm avoiding using loop

Comment: Please check if the parameters required by the functions in the USING_FUNCTION column is consistent with the value being passed to it. For example if the function is mod() and this function requires 2 parameters, if the value contained in the VALUE column is less than 2 then that will cause you an error.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) but the functions in the USING_FUNCTION column is not consistent and it only requires 1 parameter

Comment: Please explain why you want to avoid using a loop.  Post realistic example data of the function call and value from `table1`, and also from the tables used by the generated statement

Comment: you are referring to the V_value in a wrong way. It is a collection so you have to refer to it as V_value(index) not as V_value alone. If the reason why you dont want to use a loop coz its going to slow down your procedure then `forall` is your choice. It inserts your data in "bulk", not in a row by row way, which makes it a lot faster. :)

Comment: try to add another query that will execute the function since the first one is just saving it in the database as it is.

Answer (score 1):

`PLS-00306` is a compilation error.  There is a problem in the way you are using the `||` concatenation operator.   The error message includes the line number, which will allow you to identify which particular line is wrong, but this is probably the culprit: `|| V_value ||`.

It's invalid because `V_value` is a collection.  Concatenation requires a scalar variable.  If you had defined a loop referencing the index would resolve the compilation error: `|| V_value(idx) ||`.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to use a loop, then you can use `FORALL` (which is not a loop)which is a perfect pair for bulk collect. Im assuming that your V_value variable is a collection of varchar2. maybe you can declare it as a collection of record instead? On your declaration part, add the following lines:

```
           TYPE myrecord is RECORD(name table1.name%TYPE,
                                   value table1.VALUE%TYPE);
           TYPE tableofrecords is table of myrecord index by pls_integer;
           V_value tableofrecords;
```

then inside the body of your block, you can put these lines:

```
          Select name,(substr(using_function, 1, instr(using_function, '(', -1) -1)) 
    || '(' || value || ')' 
        bulk collect into V_value 
        from table1 
        where using_function != 'N';
        forall a in 1..v_value.count
             insert into table2 (name,value) values (v_value(a).name,v_value(a).value);
```

Comment: Hi, by using FORALL, I can't seem to execute the function before inserting it into the table. It will just insert 'GET_FUNCTION(-3)' into the column instead of '20' if the GET_FUNCTION(-3) is called.

Comment: You're right, you cant execute your function if you're going to use forall. You have to loop through it if you want to execute the function before inserting it in a table. That points out that you can't do what you want to achieve here without using any loop. If you can point out why you're avoiding to use a loop, maybe we can help you further..

Comment: it will but its inevitable on your case. If that's your reason, dbms_parallel_execute might help you. [Here's](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::NO:RP:P11_QUESTION_ID:4248554900346593542) something that will get you started about it

Answer (score 0):

try adding this block.It will execute the function stored in the v_value

```
execute immediate 'select '||v_value||' from dual ' into new_v_value
```

Note: new_v_value should be of array type.